# Android screen cast/mirroring to Raspberry Pi?

Tags: raspbian, android

How I can cast my Android screen to the Raspbian?

Per [this](http://www.classthink.com/2013/08/08/screen-mirroring-now-supported-on-nexus-10-nexus-7-2013-and-nexus-4-with-miracast/) Android 4.3 is added some API for easy screen casting, Settings > Device > Display > Cast screen however I couldn't find anyway to make that with Raspbian.

It is done for [Airplay](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2359972) but from some searching I've reached to [this](https://github.com/xbianonpi/xbian/issues/324) and [this](http://esrlabs.com/blog/android-transporter-for-the-nexus-7-and-the-raspberry-pi/) (needs very specific custom ROM) and I couldn't find any solution for live casting my Android device screen to use Raspberry Pi HDMI output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Miracast (what the cast setting on a Nexus enables) is tricky because it's a direct device to device Wi-Fi protocol. There appears to be a project called [OpenWFD](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/openwfd/) that's working on Linux support but it's not ready yet. You'd probably have better luck using something like [VNC](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.vmlite.vncserver&hl=en), which works reasonably well on the RaspberryPi already.

Comment: It's not clear how you would get the source Android content to transmit via  VNC, unless you plan on heavily modifying the source device's Android install, or restricting to certain apps with their own built-in VNC support.

Answer (score 3):

The MiracleCast project can turn a Raspberry Pi into a Miracast reciever or transmitter. See [here](https://github.com/albfan/miraclecast/issues/148) for a success story on a Raspberry Pi.

https://www.github.com/albfan/miraclecast

Comment: That repo doesn't have any downloads and the Pi guide sounds like it's saying to run it from a custom ISO. That's doable but I don't think most people want to dual boot their Pi. Any tips for this or newer software for this?

Answer (score 1):

It's not perfect, but I'm doing it using XPRA.

1. Shadow your normal X screen (xpra shadow :0) on your laptop
2. Log into the raspbian over SSH (with access to running X screen)
3. Attach to your laptop: xpra attach ssh:ip_address:0

cons: You won't cast a video that way, but web pages, apps, presentation - yes. You need a control inversion where raspberry pi is able to log into your (higher level security) system.

Comment: It seems like you may have misread the question.  The source is no a laptop but rather an Android device, and the mirror display is the pi.  This means you can't use an arbitrary solution, but rather only make use of functionality which the Android operating system (or failing that specific apps with the content of interest) already supports(s).

Comment: True - because I found this question when I was looking for info on how to cast Linux screen to rpi. Mea culpa.

For android my only idea is VNC server on android and client on rpi. Still not best for casting images/videos. Ex. (rooted devices): https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.onaips.vnc&hl=pl

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can install Android 11 on a Raspberry Pi 3 or 4

I have only tried one configuration

That is Android 11 via Lineage OS 18.1

This specific build

https://konstakang.com/devices/rpi4/LineageOS18/

This version only runs on a RPi4 with 2GB ram. I tried 1GB and while it ran, it was highly unstable with several application crashes before boot is finished

But on RPi4 2GB, it worked very well for my purpose, is working very well right now for a spacedesk viewer